# Conditional if then else on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, max

For the df below, I want to apply the following rules, if the value of SPY or SCZ are positive, add to the new column 'ACTIVE' the label of the column with the highest value else if neither are positive, then set value for column 'ACTIVE' to the column label of the highest value, either TLT or TIP.

```
# pseudo code rules
if df.SPY > 0 and df.SCZ > 0:
   if df.SPY > df.SCZ:
      df['ACTIVE'] = 'SPY'
   else:
      df['ACTIVE'] = 'SCZ'
else:
   if df.TIP > df.TLT:
      df['ACTIVE'] = 'TIP'
   else:
      df['ACTIVE'] = 'TLT'


#sample data
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'TLT':[0.077,0.064,0.034,0.028], 
                    'TIP':[0.021,0.014,0.005,0.005], 
                    'SPY':[0.055,-0.063,0.09,0.094],
                    'SCZ':[0.062,0.060,0.068,0.069]})

# condition is only referencing the last row, need it to apply to each row
if (df.SPY[-1:] < 0).bool() & (df.SCZ[-1:] < 0).bool():    
    df['ACTIVE'] = df.iloc[:,0:2].apply(pd.Series.idxmax, axis=1)
else:
    # this will set the last column to the highest performing asset
    df['ACTIVE'] = df.iloc[:,2:4].apply(pd.Series.idxmax, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     TLT    TIP     SPY     SCZ
0   0.077   0.021   0.055   0.062
1   0.064   0.014   -0.063  0.060
2   0.034   0.005   0.090   0.068
3   0.028   0.005   0.094   0.069
```

You can use `np.where` and do it in vectorized way.

```
df3['Active'] = np.where((df3['SPY'] > 0) & (df3['SCZ'] > 0),
                         np.where(df3['SPY'] > df3['SCZ'], 'SPY', 'SCZ'),
                         np.where(df3['TIP'] > df3['TLT'], 'TIP', 'TLT'))
df3
     TLT    TIP     SPY     SCZ     Active
0   0.077   0.021   0.055   0.062   SCZ
1   0.064   0.014   -0.063  0.060   TLT
2   0.034   0.005   0.090   0.068   SPY
3   0.028   0.005   0.094   0.069   SPY
```

Comment: yes, but you should avoid using loops while while using pandas numpy

Comment: I agree so I moved my solved check to ggaurav because of that fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` method, which will apply provided function on every row of the DataFrame.

```py
def active(row):
  if row['SPY'] > 0 and row['SCZ'] > 0:
    if row['SPY'] > row['SCZ']:
      return 'SPY'
    return 'SCZ'
  
  if row['TIP'] > row['TLT']:
    return 'TIP'

  return 'TLT'

df3['ACTIVE'] = df3.apply(active, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use for this task Python built-in *list comprehension*.

First, let's extract the logic to determine the new field to its own function:

```py
def evaluate_row(row) -> str:
    if row['SPY'] > 0 and row['SCZ'] > 0:
        if row['SPY'] > row['SCZ']:
            return 'SPY'
        else:
            return 'SCZ'
    else:
        if row['TIP'] > row['TLT']:
            return 'TIP'
        else:
            return 'TLT'
```

Now we just use this function to generate a list using *list comprehension* that will populate the new column `'ACTIVE'` in the dataframe.  Pretty simple:

```py
df3['ACTIVE'] = [evaluate_row(r[1]) for r in df3.iterrows()]
```

**NOTE**: The reason why we use `r[1]` is because of the tuple returned by `.iterrows()` method.

The result is:

```
>>> df3
     TLT    TIP    SPY    SCZ ACTIVE
0  0.077  0.021  0.055  0.062    SCZ
1  0.064  0.014 -0.063  0.060    TLT
2  0.034  0.005  0.090  0.068    SPY
3  0.028  0.005  0.094  0.069    SPY
```